# How to add a new row to table and change it's color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have to make a table in which I can dynamically add a new row. A user has to input first name, last name, age, etc. and choose a group. Depending on the user's group choice, a row with "friend" should have a particular style (for example green background color), with "family" pink background color, etc. So far I have added a new row.

How can I change the row style?

```js
function newTableRow() {

  var newRow = document.createElement("tr");

  var newFirst = document.createElement("td");
  var newLast = document.createElement("td");
  var newEmail = document.createElement("td");
  var newAge = document.createElement("td");
  var newDate = document.createElement("td");
  var newGender = document.createElement("td");
  var newGroup = document.createElement("td");

  var table = document.getElementById("tab");

  table.appendChild(newRow);
  newRow.appendChild(newFirst);
  newRow.appendChild(newLast);
  newRow.appendChild(newEmail);
  newRow.appendChild(newAge);
  newRow.appendChild(newDate);
  newRow.appendChild(newGender);
  newRow.appendChild(newGroup);

  newFirst.innerHTML = document.getElementById("first").value;
  newLast.innerHTML = document.getElementById("last").value;
  newEmail.innerHTML = document.getElementById("email").value;
  newAge.innerHTML = document.getElementById("age").value;
  newDate.innerHTML = document.getElementById("date").value;
  newGroup.innerHTML = document.getElementById("group").value;

  newGender.innerHTML = document.getElementById("gender").value;

  if (document.getElementById("group").value == "family")
    document.getElementById(newRow).className = "style1";

  if (document.getElementById("group").value == "friend")
    document.getElementById(newRow).className = "style2";

  if (document.getElementById("group").value == "work")
    document.getElementById(newRow).className = "style3";

}
```

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
}

.style1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.style2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.style3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <table id="tab">
      <tr>
        <th> First Name </th>
        <th> Last name </th>
        <th> Email </th>
        <th> Age </th>
        <th> Date of birth</th>
        <th> Gender</th>
        <th> Group</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row">
        <td id="first1"><input type="text" id="first"></td>
        <td id="last1"><input type="text" id="last"></td>
        <td id="emal1"><input type="email" id="email"></td>
        <td id="age1"><input type="number" id="age"></td>
        <td id="date1"><input type="date" id="date"></td>
        <td id="gender1">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
        </td>
        <td id="group1">
          <select id="group">
            <option value="family">family</option>
           <option value="friend">friend</option>
        <option value="work">work</option>            
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="newTableRow()">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looked the console of the dev tools, you would see that you have some syntax errors in your code. I fixed then, compare your code with mine to see.
Propably, the code below is working as you expect.

```css
#container
{
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
table, th,td
{
 border: solid black 1px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 padding:20px;
}
.style1
{
 background-color:pink;
}
.style2
{
 background-color:green;
}
.style3
{
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
<body>

     <div id="container">
    <div id="content" >
  <table id="tab">
            <tr>
              <th> First Name   </th>
           <th> Last name  </th>
        <th> Email   </th>
        <th> Age  </th>
        <th> Date of birth</th>
        <th> Gender</th>
        <th> Group</th>
        
      </tr>
      <tr id ="row">
              <td id= "first1"> <input type="text" id="first"> </td>
           <td id="last1">  <input type="text" id="last">  </td>
        <td id="emal1">  <input type="email" id="email">  </td>
           <td id="age1">  <input type="number" id="age">  </td>
        <td id="date1">  <input type="date" id="date">  </td>
        <td id="gender1">  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
                               <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male <br> </td>
        <td id="group1" >
              <select id="group">
                                   <option value="family">family</option>
                                <option value="friend">friend</option>
           <option value="work">work</option>            
                                   </select>
                         </td>
        
      </tr>
  </table>
                      
       <button onclick="newTableRow()">Add</button>
  </div>
    </div>
 
   <script>
    
    function newTableRow()
    {
    
         var newRow= document.createElement("tr");
      
      var newFirst= document.createElement("td");
      var newLast= document.createElement("td");
      var newEmail= document.createElement("td");
      var newAge= document.createElement("td");
      var newDate= document.createElement("td");
      var newGender= document.createElement("td");
      var newGroup= document.createElement("td");    
      
      var table= document.getElementById("tab");
      
      table.appendChild(newRow);   
      newRow.appendChild(newFirst);
      newRow.appendChild(newLast);
      newRow.appendChild(newEmail);
         newRow.appendChild(newAge);
      newRow.appendChild(newDate);
      newRow.appendChild(newGender);
      newRow.appendChild(newGroup);  

      newFirst.innerHTML=document.getElementById("first").value;
      newLast.innerHTML=document.getElementById("last").value;
      newEmail.innerHTML=document.getElementById("email").value;
          newAge.innerHTML=document.getElementById("age").value;
        newDate.innerHTML=document.getElementById("date").value;
         newGroup.innerHTML=document.getElementById("group").value;

    newGender.innerHTML=document.getElementById("gender1").value;

        if(document.getElementById("group").value=="family")
          newRow.className = "style1";
    
        if(document.getElementById("group").value=="friend")
          newRow.className = "style2";
    
        if(document.getElementById("group").value=="work")
          newRow.className = "style3";

     
   
    }
 
   </script>
   

</body>


</html>
```